# Git not pushing all files within a certain folder

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, repository, bitbucket

I connected to my remote repo, added all files using `git add .` and then `git commit -m "initial"` and then to push I used `git push -u -f origin workingBranch`

All files and folders within my project was pushed to my remote repo in BitBucket, except 1. See screenshots. I can't also seem to find a way to check the gitignore file either?

Thank you for any help.
[image]

[image]

[image]

**EDIT**
[image]

**EDIT 2**
[image]

Comment: What does the finder image have to do with anything? The "fictional-university-theme" is it's own repo

Comment: Git does not push *files*, it pushes *commits*. (A commit then *contains* files, but it's a package deal: you get all the files that are in the commit, and no other files. So inspect the set of files in the commit, e.g., `git ls-tree -r`.) And as @evolutionxbox said, it looks like `ficitonal-university-theme` is a *gitlink*, i.e., a reference to a commit in a separate repository.

Comment: @torek that makes some sense. But I was trying to add all files including the fictional-university-theme folder into the commit as well. I even deleted the old git repo and created a new one in the parent wp-content folder instead to try and accomplish this?

Comment: @evolutionxbox but I deleted the old repo from the fictional-university-theme directory? Attached new finder image above with hidden files made visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I deleted the old repo from the fictional-university-theme directory?

That would not be enough, the gitlink entry might still be registered in the index of the repository.

Try

```bash
cd /path/to/repository/themes
# where fictional-university-theme  was

# no trailing / at the end:
git rm --cached -- fictional-university-theme   

git commit -m "fictional-university-theme"
```

You also need to remove any `fictional-university-theme` in your repository `.gitmodules` file.

If you still have the `fictional-university-theme` folder present, you now can add it, commit it and push it to your repository.

To fully remove a submodule though, the official command is [`git submodule deinit`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162000/6309).

Comment: Thank you so much. Sadly, this didn't work for me. Can you check my terminal to see if I've done what you asked? Screenshot in original question as EDIT 2

Comment: @AbdulSamad Check if you have a `.gitmodules` file, and remove in it any reference to `fictional-university-theme`

Comment: I found 1 line in the index file within the git. folder but after I try to added files to comit, it says:
error: index uses  extension, which we do not understand
fatal: index file corrupt

I might just try and learn how to do submodules now! :(

Comment: @AbdulSamad I have included a link to explain how you would properly remove a submodule.